# how create medium integrity level process from low integrity level process?

Tags: internet-explorer, protected-mode

If I run IE in protected mode, its integrity level is low. And if I then create a medium integrity level process (impl by ActiveX), IE will warn the user with an Elevation Warning window.

How do I create a medium process from another processes (like chrome) with a low integrity level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do what Internet Explorer (and Chrome) do. The browser tabs themselves are separate processes running at **Low Mandatory Integrity Level**. But there is still a **Medium** level parent process.

The client processes communicate back to the "parent" process though named pipes, asking the parent to perform some action. Since the parent is medium, it can launch something at medium.