# create medium level child process from low level parent process?

Tags: internet-explorer, child-process

This question might be duplicated one with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254711/how-create-medium-integrity-level-process-from-low-integrity-level-process). But this old question did not provide how to do specifically. I want to know in detail. I want to create at least medium mandatory level child process from low mandatory level parent process. For example, Internet explorer is low level process, thus child process is still low level process. This causes failure of writing on disk. How can I create at least medium level child process from Internet explorer? I have tried so much time but could not resolve this problem. Please hlp me. Any ideas will be welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have googled and found out very similar question. But that question did not provide specific way how to solve problem. That's why I am asking again. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: If you think a question needs more clarification for your purposes, please just post a comment on the question instead of asking a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is no. The old question has pointed out *there is still a **Medium** level parent process* in IE. That's why it can launch something at medium.

You could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331976/elevating-from-low-to-medium-integrity?noredirect=1&lq=1). It explains more detailed. From [the article](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2009/01/internet-explorer-in-protected-mode-how-the-low-integrity-environment-gets-created/) mentioned in the accepted answer we can also find this:

> By default, IE runs in protected mode with a low integrity level (IL). As a low IL process, IE can only write to a handful of locations that have been specifically marked with an IL of low.